# Verilog module for ALU but doesn't work properly

Tags: verilog, iverilog

I am trying to write down ALU for verilog.
And there are several error I experiences.

First of all, here is my code:

```
module yAlu(z, ex, a, b, op);

input [31:0] a, b;
input [2:0] op;
output [31:0] z, ztemp;
output ex; 
wire[31:0]a0,a1,a2,a3,a4, atemp;

assign slt = 0; 
assign ex = 0; 

assign a0 = a & b;
assign a1 = a | b;
assign a2 = a + b;
assign a3 = a - b;
assign a4 = a[31] ^ b[31];

yMux #(32) lo(zLo, a0, a1, op[0]);  
yMux #(32) hi(zHi, a2, a3, op[0]);
yMux #(32) temp(atemp, zLo, zHi, op[1]);
assign z = (op[2] == 1) ? a4 : atemp; 
assign slt = z;

endmodule
```

And yAlu.v uses following:

```
module yMux(z, a, b, c);
parameter SIZE = 2;
output [SIZE-1:0] z;
input [SIZE-1:0] a, b;
input c;
yMux1 mine[SIZE-1:0](z, a, b, c); // 2-­bit  2 -­to-­1  mux  and  it  would  be  cumbersome  to  write  32  mux  instantiation  lines.
endmodule
```

Lastly above yMux uses following:

```
module yMux1(z, a, b, c);
output z;
input a, b, c;
wire notC, upper, lower;
// Gates and interconnections for MUX

// if c is 0, z=a.
// if c is 1, z=b
not my_not(notC, c);
and upperAnd(upper, a, notC);
and lowerAnd(lower, c, b);
or my_or(z, upper, lower);
endmodule
```

Here is is what it tests above yAlu:

```
module lab8;

reg [31:0] a, b;
reg [31:0] expect;
reg [2:0] op;
wire ex;
wire [31:0] z;
reg ok, flag;
yAlu mine(z, ex, a, b, op);

initial begin

repeat (10) begin

a = $random; b = $random;

if(op==0)
expect = a & b;
else if (op==1)
expect = a | b;
else if (op==2)
expect = a + b;
else if (op==3)
expect = a - b;
else if (op==4)
expect = (a < b) ? 1 : 0;

#1;

if(expect == z)     
$display("PASS : expected=%d, a=%d, b=%d, z=%d, op=%d", expect,a,b,z,op);

#1;

$finish;  
end 
end
endmodule
```

My questions in order as follow:

```
Question 1.
```

Code above only works for 0 and 1. It doesn't work more than that.
For example, on the 2nd source code, there is

a = $random; b = $random;

it doesn't work for this. it only works when a=1 or 0 and b=1 or 0.

```
Question 2.
```

I am not sure "slt" function is working correctly. The instructor who teaches this never told me what slt does in lecture but have us design slt, by googling or something.

```
Question 3.
```

Whenever I compile, i get following Error. Why is this?

```
    yAlu.v:38: warning: Port 1 (z) of yMux expects 32 bits, got 1.
    yAlu.v:38:        : Padding 31 high bits of the port.
    yAlu.v:39: warning: Port 1 (z) of yMux expects 32 bits, got 1.
    yAlu.v:39:        : Padding 31 high bits of the port.
    yAlu.v:40: warning: Port 2 (a) of yMux expects 32 bits, got 1.
    yAlu.v:40:        : Padding 31 high bits of the port.
    yAlu.v:40: warning: Port 3 (b) of yMux expects 32 bits, got 1.
    yAlu.v:40:        : Padding 31 high bits of the port.

I can't fix this at all.
```

I don't even know I am doing it correctly. The manual that directs me to do what it says has no enough explanation as well as no sample output.

I couldn't finish in time anyway, so I guess it doesn't matter but I think I have to know solution for my problems.

Thank you very much if you can help me out.

Answer (score 3):

As shown by the warnings, your **port connection width are mismatched**. Refer to single warning and other are the same to tackle.

```
  yAlu.v:38: warning: Port 1 (z) of yMux expects 32 bits, got 1.
    yAlu.v:38:        : Padding 31 high bits of the port.
```

The module declares ports `a`,`b`,`c` and `z`, each of width defined by `SIZE` parameter.

```
module yMux(z, a, b, c);
parameter SIZE = 2;
output [SIZE-1:0] z;
input [SIZE-1:0] a, b;
```

Moreover, the `SIZE` is **overridden** while instantiating. Now, the value of `SIZE` is 32. Hence the **width of each** of `a`,`b`,`c` and `z` is **32-bits**.

```
yMux #(32) lo(zLo, a0, a1, op[0]);  
yMux #(32) hi(zHi, a2, a3, op[0]);
yMux #(32) temp(atemp, zLo, zHi, op[1]);
```

Here, the ports `zLo`,`zHi` is **not declared** and **used directly** in port connection.

Referring to [IEEE 1800-2012](https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2013/02/25/get-your-ieee-1800/), section 6.10- Implicit declarations:

> If an identifier is used in a port expression declaration, then an
>   implicit net of default net type shall be assumed, with the vector
>   width of the port expression declaration.

This, if an **undeclared identifier** is used as a connection to an instance then an **implicit net** is inferred.

Thus, `zLo`,`zHi` are **implicitly declared** as single bit **nets** and the **rest 32-bits** are **padded with zeros**. Just **declare** them as follows and **all warnings** shall be **removed**:

```
wire [31:0] zLo,zHi;
```

To get an **error** in such a situation, use `default_nettype none` compiler directive.

For more information, refer [Sutherland SV Gotchas](http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2006-SNUG-Boston_standard_gotchas_paper.pdf) paper, section 2.2 and [SystemVerilog IEEE 1800-2012](https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2013/02/25/get-your-ieee-1800/) for implicit declarations.

Comment: Is there a way to set implicitly declared wires as 32-bits without explicitly declaring them?

Comment: It is generally undesirable to declare wires implicitly. However, you can refer a [blog link here](http://hereitellyouwhatilearnttoday.blogspot.in/2012/11/disable-implicit-declaration-of-wires.html). You can give it a try.